# Trying to use two sub queries to get min and max price of houses from database using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to use SQL in Access to get the minimum and maximum prices of different types of houses which are held by an estate agent and then to be grouped by type of house.

This is the SQL I have so far, which can only get the minimum or maximum but not both.

```
SELECT Price, PropertyType
FROM SaleProperty
WHERE Price IN (SELECT MAX (Price) FROM SaleProperty GROUP BY PropertyType);
```

The code which I thought would work is:

```
SELECT Price, PropertyType
FROM SaleProperty
WHERE Price IN (SELECT MAX (Price) FROM SaleProperty GROUP BY PropertyType)
WHERE Price IN (SELECT MIN (price) FROM SaleProperty GROUP BY PropertyType);
```

But it doesn't, I get a syntax error which says missing operator.

The output should look like this:

```
MinimumPrice      MaximumPrice      PropertyType
£99999999         £9999999999       Terrace
£1111111          £1111111111       Semi-detached
£3333333          £4444444444       Link
```

Last SQL question tonight I promise!

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT Min(Price), Max(Price), PropertyType
FROM SaleProperty
Group by PropertyType
```

Answer (score 2):

You get a syntax error because a query cannot have multiple `WHERE` clauses. When you have more than one condition, there needs to be a logical operator, such as an `OR` or an `AND`, connecting them.

You can rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT Price, PropertyType
FROM SaleProperty
WHERE Price IN (SELECT MAX (Price) FROM SaleProperty GROUP BY PropertyType)
   OR Price IN (SELECT MIN (price) FROM SaleProperty GROUP BY PropertyType);
```

Note: I assume that you do it this way rather than requesting both `MIN` and `MAX` in a single row because you plan to add more columns to the `SELECT` list, which this query lets you do.

Comment: When using this I get the error "At most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Comment: @MichaelDelahorne You're right, I missed the `GROUP BY` inside the subqueries. Try it now and see if it works.

Comment: This does show both the minimum and maximum prices so thank you! Is there any way to seperate the minimum and maximum into their own columns? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelahorne Yes, but then you would not be able to get other attributes from the row. Take one of your subqueries, add the second column (`MIN` or `MAX`), and a `PropertyType` column, and you will get the `MIN` and `MAX` prices in separate columns.